# Is it possible to use a container parameter defined in a bundle to autowire an optional interface for services in that bundle only?

Tags: symfony

A custom Symfony bundle is used to add code different projects of mine. One services uses an **optional** parameter with an interface as type hint. If the parameter is `null` depends on whether autowire knows what to inject for the interface. In the following example the project tells autowire to use `SomeClass` for **all** `SomeInterface` parameters:

```
// The interface with in the bundle 
interface SomeInterface { }

// The method to be autowired within the bundle
public function doSomething(SomeInterface $some) { 
    if (null !== $some) {
        $some->thing();
    }
}

// service.yaml within the PROJECT
Name\Space\SomeInterface: '@Name\Space\SomeClass'
```

This works fine and when the line `Name\Space\SomeInterface: '@Name\Space\SomeClass'` is removed, the services works with `$some = null`.

While it works, this approach has one major draw back: **All** parameters of type `SomeInterface` are autowired with `SomeClass`. If multiple bundles would use `SomeInterface` it would not be possible to tell autowire to use `SomeClass` for BundleA and `OtherClass` for BundleB.

To solve this, I could move the autowire config to the bundle and move it with a container parameter:

```
// service.yaml within the BUNDLE
Name\Space\SomeInterface: '%mybundle.some_interface%'

// config/packages/bundleA.yaml in PROJECT
mybundle:
    some_interface: '@Name\Space\SomeClass'
```

While this looks promising, it does not work:

> A service definition must be an array or a string starting with "@"
> but "string" found for service "Name\Space\SomeInterface" in
> "/bundleA/config/services.yaml".    Check your YAML syntax.

It seems that `%bundleA.some_interface%` is not properly replaced by `@Name\Space\SomeClass` (although `php bin/console debug:container --parameters` shows, that `bundleA.some_interface` is properly set).

**So, is there any way to define an interface for autowire using a container parameter?**

Comment: How are these different ways distinguished? Do you use a seperate name (such that you could use `bind`)?

Comment: You mean how to set different classes for different bundles? `BundleA` could accept `bundleA.interface` and `BundleB` would use `bundleB.interface` (defined in their `Configuration.php`). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: So, the specific service to be used is different per bundle, but always the same within one bundle?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.